# Displaying object status in table (icon)

Tags: swift, macos

I want to show the status of an object within my NSTableView.
For example, plesae look onto the screenshot below. Caching, File Sharing, Mail, Profile Manage, Websites and Wiki have a green icon near their "tab".

Status is defined by the following within my Device class:

```
var online: Bool = false
```

When it's online, the bool says true, if not, it's false ;)

Any ideas how I can bring this to the following?

[image]

(This is an older screenshot, I want the icon on the left side of the "test" name /label. The status table column has already been removed, I first thought this would be a solution but it wasn't what I am looking for)

[image]

Comment: The sky is limitless.  So is the possibility for an answer for your question.  Or be more specific as to where you face difficulty programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use view based table view.
- Use a table cell view with text field **and** image view.
- Set the image to `NSImage(named: NSImageNameStatusAvailable)` or other depending on `online`.